# the value of type file is empty

Tags: php, html, forms

i have an html form which have one textfield and one file field. when i click on submit button the value of file field is posting empty. i do not know what error i am doing. the follwing is my code..

```
<? include "conn.php"; ?>
<? if($_POST['upload'] != "" || $_POST['upload'] != NULL) {
$q="insert into img values('".$_Post['img']."')";
echo $q;
echo $_POST['txtname'];
  echo $_POST['img']; 
  }
   ?>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">

<table>
    <tr>
    <td>select image</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="img" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="txtname"></td>
     td><input type="submit" name="upload" class="upload" value="select" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
<? 
if(isset($_POST['upload']) {
    $q="insert into img values('".$_FILES['img']['name']."')";
    echo $q;
    echo $_POST['txtname'];
    echo $_FILES['img']['name']; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with `$_FILES` like

```
if($_FILES['upload'] != "" || $_FILES['upload'] != NULL) {
```

All the input of type `file` will be identified as `$_FILES`.And while checking you can also try with `isempty()` like

```
if(!isempty($_FILES['uplaod']))
```

And echo the file name as

```
echo $_FILES['img']['name'];
```

Comment: `when i click on submit button the value of file field is posting empty`

Comment: it should display the image name @Gautam3164

Answer (score 0):

Not sure sir, but you form action should be `./` instead of null.

Also, are you closing your form tag?

Can you see the other Post elements? If so, ignore the first line and consider debugging a little bit or, rather, post your entire code!